# Collapsing Values to the Left, Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I work with a dataset that occasionally have values removed before I get my hands on it.  When a value is removed, it is generally replaced my NaN or ''.  What is the most efficient way to collapse the values to the left?

Specifically, I'm trying to turn this:

```
          1       2        3         4
bill    sjd              meoip  
nick            tredsn              bana
fred    ccrw    aaaa     cretwew    bbbbb
tom                      eomwepo     
jill            dew                 weaedf
```

Into this:

```
          1         2      3         4
bill    sjd       meoip     
nick    tredsn    bana      
fred    ccrw      aaaa    cretwew   bbbbb
tom     eomwepo         
jill    dew       weaedf
```

The column titles don't matter, the only thing that matters is that there are no leading empty cells and no empty cells between.

I would prefer to do this in a non-iterative fashion, as the df can be quite large.

Comment: please post code and data, not images of such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if those blanks are '', then use mask to np.nan, else you don't need `mask` nor `fillna`:

```
df.mask(df == '').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values), axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
           0      1        2     3
bill     sjd  meojp               
nick  tredsn   bana               
fred    ccrw   aaaa  cretwew  bbbb
tom   eomwep                      
jill     dew  weadf
```